# Java8 streams collectors.ToMap Method reference failing

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, collectors, method-reference

Can someone tell me what is the issue in following example code.
For sake of example, We can assume all columns are available in resultSet and everything is a String.

Last line in below code is failing.

```
ResultSet rs = JdbcTemplate.query(......)

List<String> columnName= <some predefined fixed values> ;


Map<String,String> columnAndValueMap 
                = columnName
                      .stream()
                      .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                                   Function.identity(),
                                   rs::getString)); //Cannot resolve method 'getString'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @fps mentioned, the `rs.getString()` method throws a SQLException as described in its signature.

Assuming you are seeking to create a map with column names as keys and result set strings as values, you can do:

```
List<String> columnNames = List.of("columnA", "columnB");

Map<String, Object> map = columnNames.stream().collect(
        Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), s -> {
            try {
                return Optional.ofNullable(rs.getString(s));
            } catch (SQLException throwables) {
                throwables.printStackTrace();
            }
            return s;
        }));
```

This is a bit messy since you need to catch the `SQLException` during the stream operations.  Further, an encouraged practice is to use `Optional` since the `getString()` method can return a null.  (Understood that you are assuming that there will be no nulls. Your IDE may highlight the lack of `Optional` as a warning.)

You may instead be better off using a simple for loop and surround it with a try/catch:

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>(columnNames.size());
for (String columnName : columnNames) {
    try {
        map.put(columnName, rs.getString(columnName));
    } catch (SQLException throwables) {
        throwables.printStackTrace(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: @vphilipnyc Yeah, I end up using foreach loop in the end... thanks for solution

Comment: Totally fine if you give the answer from @fps the checkmark as it directly addresses the question.  Just trying to help with some sample code.

Answer (score 3):

`Collectors.toMap` expects a `Function<String, String>` as its second argument (the value mapper function).

`Function<String, String>` is a functional interface that has this single abstract method:

```
String apply(String arg);
```

However, the `ResultSet.getString` method has the following signature:

```
String getString(String columnLabel) throws SQLException;
```

As `SQLException` is a checked exception, it makes the `ResultSet.getString` method incompatible with the `Function.apply` method, hence you're getting that error.

---

As shown by @vphilipnyc in [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64761756/1876620), you can use a `for` loop with a `try/catch` block to handle your scenario. Or, if you want to stick to a more functional approach, you might declare your own functional interface, that adapts a `SQLException` throwing function to a common `java.util.function.Function` (via inheritance):

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface SQLFunction<T, R> extends Function<T, R> {

    R applySQL(T t) throws SQLException;

    @Override
    default R apply(T t) {
        try {
            return applySQL(t);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e); // or your own unchecked exception
        }
    }

    static <T, R> Function<T, R> adapt(SQLFunction<T, R> f) {
        return f;
    }
}
```

Then, you could use it this way:

```
Map<String, String> columnAndValueMap = columnName.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        Function.identity(),
        SQLFunction.adapt(rs::getString)));
```

Comment: There is no need to create a new object via `return f::apply;` as you can simply use `return f;`, as `SQLFunction` has been designed as subtype of `Function`.

Comment: @Holger True, no need for the method reference, thanks. Fixed!